# Building a list in a loop - avoid using MutableList

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Is there a way I can build a list without using `MutableList` when I need to call a api synchronously in a loop? I need to call the api synchronously because the response is paged.. so I get 10 results back per response, then I request the next page. Although, having said that,  after the first request I know exactly how many pages there are (in the response I get `totalPages`) so I could theoretically make async requests for the remaining data

The code below works - but can I do the same thing more elegantly? Possibly using async FP, without `vars` and a `MutableList`

```
  private fun getAllCustomers(): List<Customer> {
    var pageNumber = 0
    var totalPages = 1
    val allCustomers: MutableList<Customer> = mutableListOf()
    while (pageNumber < totalPages) {
      val response = customerApi.getCustomers(alphaChar, pageNumber)
      totalPages = response.totalPages
      pageNumber ++
      allCustomers.addAll(response.content)
    }
    return allCustomers
  }
```

Comment: I don't know kotlin, but probably you want a flat-map, so (using pseudocode): `flatmap( pageNumber => customerApi.getCustomers(alphaChar, pageNumber), range(totalPages))`

Comment: In your code above, it looks like you are calling a blocking, synchronous API function. Most APIs provide a way to request something asynchronously with a callback, or synchronously with a suspend function. So the solution will depend on what is available from the API. Is totalPages a value that gets returned with each response but never changes, and you simply don’t know what it is until the first call? Does the API response tell you which page number it’s returning?

Comment: So, after looking up some syntax, you can do something like `val allCustomers: MutableList<Customer> = (1..totalPages).flatMap { pageNumber -> customerApi.getCustomers(alphaChar, pageNumber) }`

Comment: @Tenfour04  yes - totalPages gets returned by each response but never changes . I can call the api asynchronously.. but need to tell which page number I want on each request. I only know the totalPages after the first request

Comment: Any problem/ issue using `MutableList` here?

Comment: @Quantum_VC - I believe it is preferable to use a ```List``` if a ```MutableList``` can be avoided. Of course, maybe the answer is that MutableList cannot be avoided here

Comment: List is preferable for better encapsulation when you’re passing something around between classes or threads. Since this MutableList is private to the function scope, there’s no advantage in avoiding it.